# Is "cuerina" ≈ "artificial leather"?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, argentina, ropa

In Argentina we use the word "cuerina" to refer to something I have the below clues, it's called "imitation leather" in english. Am I right?

There is no "cuerina" wikipedia article in the Spanish Wikipedia.

But [this page](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/cuerina.html) suggests it's translated "imitation leather" many times and once as "synthetic leather".

I wonder if this concept coincides or it is only a subset of [artificial leather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_leather). There is no spanish article for artifitial leather, though.

[According to this](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/traducir/espanol-ingles/cuerina) "pleather" is another possibility, and this is close to the previous wiki link.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Are you asking about translating a Spanish term into English? If so, you'd better ask this question in some of the sites about the English language, that are more suitable to find expressions in English.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Good point! I think I can keep the question here because I'm want to know what "cuerina" means in Spanish, and this is Spanish stack exchange, so it makes perfect sense. Asking for a translation to English is indeed specific to the English language, but since is the common language of the internet (with my utmost respect for all languages), it doesn't seem crazy to me.  I want to know what is "cuerina" precisely, and a translation to English would satisfy that for me.

Comment: @Santopedro: Then perhaps you should modify the title of the question asking for the **meaning** of cuerina.

Comment: Never heard that word in Spain. If I had to guess, I would say fake leather as you suggested.

Comment: @SergioTx Very helpful! I know it's used in Argentina. I added the tag just in case.

Comment: The word is used in Colombia too and you are correct. Any synthetic material imitating the look and texture of leather is call **cuerina**

Comment: I don't see the difference between synthetic leather and artificial leather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first place to look for a word in Spanish should be the DRAE and not the Wikipedia:

> **[cuerina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BadneCq)**
>
> De *cuero*.
>
> 1. f. Arg., Hond. y Ur. Material sintético fino que se usa en el calzado de mala calidad y en muebles como sustituto del cuero.

So yes, *cuerina* seems to be some kind of artificial or synthetic leather. Besides, if some term happens to be missing from the dictionary, you can always look for its root, prefixes or suffixes. In this case:

> **[-ino, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LhBJAGL)**
>
> Del lat. *-īnus* o *-ĭnus*, lat. vulg. *-īnus*.
>
> 2. suf. Designa materia o semejanza.

This should also give a clue that *cuerina* is some material similar to *cuero*.

Answer (score 0):

In Argentina *cuerina* is preferred to real leather but is from lower layers because is softer and more manageable. Used for jackets, skirts and any other item of clothing that needs to be very flexible.

Comment: ¿La cuerina es del animal, o se fabrica?  ¿Dices que la cuerina sería lo que se usa para hacer guantes finos ("kid gloves")?  Quizás en un principio era del animal, pero Google Images sugiere que ahora es artificial....

Answer (score 0):

According to the following website, *cuero ecológico*, *cuero sintético*, and *cuerina*, are all synonymous:

> El cuero ecológico, **también conocido como cuero sintético o cuerina**, tiene una textura similar a la que se obtiene de una vaca u otro animal. Se trata de un producto cuya materia prima no se obtiene por procedimientos tradicionales, tal y como se ha hecho durante miles de años.
>
> - [*Definición ABC* - Qué es Cuero Ecológico](https://www.definicionabc.com/medio-ambiente/cuero-ecologico.php)

Looking at how it is used online, it doesn't seem to have a 'scientific' definition, and is used variously as a synonym for artificial leather generally, artificial leathers made from petroleum, or to contrast with [artificial leather made from natural products.](https://www.vice.com/es_co/article/9b4jm5/el-cuero-a-base-de-fibras-de-pia-que-revolucionar-el-mundo-textil)

Answer (score 0):

Ive read a lot about this and yes.
There is three "types of leather"
- Real one. 100% Animal. 100% biodegradable.
- Compund Leather, also knows as bounded, eco friendly and PU. Thats just a backing of real animal fiber with an chequical compund that imitates color and texture. This is what we call "Cuerina" in spanish. Very common on jackets that later flake off out of the blue. This has no cure other than removing the whole coating and end up with suede-like materia. Or gamusa. You can wax and shine this material to kind of have a new finish, but looses its texture.
- Finaly Fake leather, leather imitation or PVC. This is what we call "Vinilo" in spanish. This is 100% synthetic, man made from Plastic. This one rather than flaking, cracks and reveal a wool like fiber. Is "easier" to repair small cracking  damage couse you can apply tins and coats to make it look just like new. But since the new coating is over a weak base, it will continue cracking and falling of eventually. This is much more water resistant that PU and real leather... Couse is plastic.

Comment: Welcome to te site. Proper editing would make this answer easier to read and understand. Please, check [tour], [help] and [answer].